# Как создать пустой gradle проект в intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, project

Как создать пустой gradle проект?
В интернете, буквально, нигде не написано, почему у меня его нету в меню создания. Возможно, на офф сайте jetBrains и есть информация, сайт в Казахстане мне недоступен.
Я уже переустановил три версии intellij, поустанавливал все, в чем есть слово gradle, но ничего не поменялось.

Что не так? Мне нужен проект для многомодульного приложения

[image: Как выглядит меню intellij idea]

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно выбрать просто New Project:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и дальше создастся проект с таким +/- градл файлом:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

и можно будет запустить с gradle:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[вот туториал](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html#create_project) по работе с такими проектами